# "躋春臺" PDF version?

Tags: resources

Wikisource has a copy of [躋春臺](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E8%BA%8B%E6%98%A5%E8%87%BA) (or "Mounting Spring Platform" as I've seen it crudely translated before) online.

It is missing *rare* characters though. Here is one example:

《四川方言词源》has the entry **门** which gives historical literary usage from 躋春臺:

> 清刘省三《跻春台》卷一《东瓜女》： “将近门， 正逢东瓜女抱儿在外。”

But if we look at wikisource's page for [東瓜女](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E8%BA%8B%E6%98%A5%E8%87%BA/03) it only reads:

> 將近門，正逢東瓜女抱兒在外

---

There are tons of txt / epub / text turned pdf versions floating all over the web, but they all contain the same errors.

Are there any scanned copies of this original text in pdf format anywhere? Including the four volumes of 躋春臺 (元集, 亨集, 利集, 貞集)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [djvu version](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/so.php?sokeytm=%E8%BA%8B%E6%98%A5%E8%87%BA&ka=100) can be downloaded from the 國學大師 site.

[image]

Comment: Hey, this seems to only be 上, is there a 下 as well? Edit: is this the second volume: http://www.guoxuedashi.com/guji/232815a/ ? I'm pretty sure it is.

Comment: btw p. 86 of 上 has the exact example I gave above, if you can add the second volume and a 截图 of page 86 that would be golden.